# Asp.net Repeater Find Control

Tags: c#, html, find, controls

HTML input within a repeater I'm trying to get value of the checkbox but can't find

```
    foreach (RepeaterItem ri in RpSorular.Items)
    {
        HtmlInputCheckBox DegerA = (HtmlInputCheckBox)ri.FindControl("DegerA");

        if (DegerA.Checked)
        {
            Response.Write(DegerA.Value);
        }
    }
```

Comment: <input type="checkbox" name="DegerA" value="<%#Eval("DegerA") %>" />

The HTML like this.

Comment: Use Request.Form to get the checkbox value